# How to display custom attribute name after login into site in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, header, name

I want to display custom attribute name after welcome message when login in to site. I have added custom attribute in "full_name" in customer account so i need to display this full name after welcome message in header after login in to site.

My `Header.php` file is

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('page/html/header.phtml');
    }

    public function getIsHomePage()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('') == $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
    }

    public function setLogo($logo_src, $logo_alt)
    {
        $this->setLogoSrc($logo_src);
        $this->setLogoAlt($logo_alt);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogoSrc()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['logo_src'])) {
            $this->_data['logo_src'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src');
        }
        return $this->getSkinUrl($this->_data['logo_src']);
    }

    public function getLogoSrcSmall()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['logo_src_small'])) {
            $this->_data['logo_src_small'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src_small');
        }
        return $this->getSkinUrl($this->_data['logo_src_small']);
    }

    public function getLogoAlt()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['logo_alt'])) {
            $this->_data['logo_alt'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');
        }
        return $this->_data['logo_alt'];
    }

    public function getWelcome()
    {
        if (empty($this->_data['welcome'])) {
            if (Mage::isInstalled() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = $this->__('Welcome, %s!', $this->escapeHtml(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()));
            } else {
                $this->_data['welcome'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/welcome');
            }
        }

        return $this->_data['welcome'];
    }
}
```

Anybody knows answer please share. I am new in Magento.

Comment: please help me someone

Comment: It is bad idea to overwrite the core files. Try to change the corresponding template in your theme.